# React scripts issue: loop loading chunk.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using React scripts v3. I have this issue whenever I do an action of in the page ( mouse event, forms...) the application keeps downloading **chunk.js**

[image]

This my **package.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "lodash.flatten": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.intersection": "^4.4.0",
    "mockdate": "^2.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^6.0.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "mocks": "cd mocks && npm start",
    "start-dotnet": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run mocks\" \"react-scripts start\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "set NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu&& react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "test:staged": "npm run test -- --coverage --findRelatedTests --watchAll=false",
    "test-coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage --watchAll=false"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*src/**/*.js": [
      "prettier --write",
      "npm run test:coverage",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "commitlint": {
    "extends": [
      "@commitlint/config-conventional"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "ie 11",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^8.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.0",
    "full-icu": "^1.3.0",
    "husky": "^2.4.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest-cucumber": "^2.0.11",
    "lint-staged": "^8.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about this issue?

Comment: Never encountered this surprising issue. could you please provide an [mcve]?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm on react-scripts 3.3.0 and I get this sometimes too. Kinda randomly happens.

Comment: im getting this also today - no idea why yet

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, where it kept on requesting for chunk.
It happened because there was a reference issue inside my JS chunk that I was lazy loading.
So I was lazy loading page data, and inside the JS for that, I was doing an import to a file that did not exists. And that lead to this issue.

Fixing that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today. I had incorrectly set the onChange action to a string instead of a function, so changing it to a function worked for me.